# Show 0 when printing nodes near coords in chart bar

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

**Problem description:**

I would like for all values including 0 to be shown above bars in a chart bar. As I am new to latex, I assume something is set in nodes near coords that prevents 0 from showing. With my current MWE, I am getting the following output:
[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
1,0,19,0,13
2,0,12,2,9
3,10,0,8,2
4,22,1,15,1
}\data

\pgfplotsset{
    percentage plot/.style={
        point meta=explicit,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        align=left,
        font=\footnotesize,
    }, 
    nodes near coords={
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}
         \ifnum\iszero=0
         \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=0]
        {\originalvalue}\\
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}$\%$
        \fi}, 
    nodes near coords style={font=\tiny},     
    nodes near coords align=vertical,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=23,
    enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.1}, 
    visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
    },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    width=14cm,
    ybar,
    percentage plot,bar width=12pt,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4},
    xtick=data,
    legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
        anchor=north,
            column sep=1ex}, 
]
\addplot [style={teal,fill=teal}] coordinates {(1,0)[0] (2,0)[0] (3,10)[31] (4,22)[69]};
\addplot [style={blue,fill=blue}] coordinates {(1,19)[59] (2,12)[38] (3,0)[0] (4,1)[3]};
\addplot [style={violet,fill=violet}] coordinates {(1,0)[0] (2,2)[8] (3,8)[32] (4,15)[60]};
\addplot [style={cyan,fill=cyan}] coordinates {(1,13)[52] (2,9)[36] (3,2)[8] (4,1)[4]};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

**Desired result**
I would like to have 0 and 0% written where there are no bars shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

The idea is to remove the `if` test and the `fi` test closing.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
1,0,19,0,13
2,0,12,2,9
3,10,0,8,2
4,22,1,15,1
}\data

\pgfplotsset{
    percentage plot/.style={
        point meta=explicit,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        align=left,
        font=\footnotesize,
    }, 
    nodes near coords={
%         \ifnum\iszero=0  % <-- changed here
         \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=0]
        {\originalvalue}\\
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}$\%$
%        \fi  % <-- changed here
}, 
    nodes near coords style={font=\tiny},     
    nodes near coords align=vertical,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=23,
    enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.1}, 
    visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
    },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    width=14cm,
    ybar,
    percentage plot,bar width=12pt,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4},
    xtick=data,
    legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
        anchor=north,
            column sep=1ex}, 
]
\addplot [style={teal,fill=teal}] coordinates {(1,0)[0] (2,0)[0] (3,10)[31] (4,22)[69]};
\addplot [style={blue,fill=blue}] coordinates {(1,19)[59] (2,12)[38] (3,0)[0] (4,1)[3]};
\addplot [style={violet,fill=violet}] coordinates {(1,0)[0] (2,2)[8] (3,8)[32] (4,15)[60]};
\addplot [style={cyan,fill=cyan}] coordinates {(1,13)[52] (2,9)[36] (3,2)[8] (4,1)[4]};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe clean the preamble ... And I would probably delete `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}` as well and set `every node near coord/.append style={align=center}`.

Comment: Yes, like that! I have actually tried deleting if statement but haven't deleted fi (did not know that this closes the if statement) and there was obviously some error. I was wondering the whole time why I need this fi :) Thank you!

Comment: @sabinagorenc, yes. There is `\if \else \fi` command.